# Postgres full text search against arbitrary data - possible or not?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, amazon-rds

I was hoping to get some advice or guidance around a problem I'm having.

We currently store event data in Postgres 12 (AWS RDS) - this data could contain anything. To reduce the amount of data (alot of keys for example are common across all events) we flatten this data and store it across 3 tables -

event_keys - the key names from events
event_values - the values from events
event_key_values - a lookup table, containing the event_id, and key_id and value_id.

First inserting the key and value (or returning the existing id), and finally storing the ids in the event_key_values table. So 2 simple events such as

```js
[
  {
    "event_id": 1,
    "name": "updates",
    "meta": {
      "id": 1,
      "value: "some random value"
    }
  },
  {
    "event_id": 2,
    "meta": {
      "id": 2,
      "value: "some random value"
    }
  }
]
```

would become

**event_keys**

```
id  key
1   name
2   meta.id
3   meta.value
```

**event_values**

```
id  value
1   updates
2   1
3   some random value
4   2
```

**event_key_values**

```
event_id  key_id  value_id
1         1       1
1         2       2
1         3       3
2         2       4
2         3       3
```

All values are converted to text before storing, and a GIN index has been added to the event_key and event_values tables.

When attempting to search this data, we are able to retrieve results, however once we start hitting 1 million or more rows (we are expecting billions!) this can take anywhere from 10 seconds too minutes to find data. The key-values could have multiple search operations applied to them - equality, contains (case-sensitive and case-insensitive) and regex. To complicate things a bit more, the user can also search against **all** events, or a filtered selection (so only search against the last 10 days, events belonging to a certain application etc).

Some things I have noticed from testing

- searching with multiple WHERE conditions on the same key e.g meta.id, the GIN index is used. However, a WHERE condition with multiple keys does not hit the index.
- searching with multiple WHERE conditions on both the event_keys and event_values table does not hit the GIN index.
- using 'raw' SQL - we use Jooq in this project and this was to rule out any issues caused by it's SQL generation.

I have tried a few things

- denormalising the data and storing everything in one table - however this resulted in the database (200 GB disk) becoming filled within a few hours, with the index taking up more space than the data.
- storing the key-values as a JSONB value against an event_id, the JSON blob containing the flattened key-value pairs as a map - this had the same issues as above, with the index taking up 1.5 times the space as the data.
- building a document from the available key-values using concatenation using both a sub-query and CTE - from testing with a few million rows this takes forever, even when attempting to tune some parameters such as *work_mem*!

From reading solutions and examples here, it seems full text search provides the most benefits and performance when applied against known columns e.g. a table with **first_name**, **last_name** and a GIN index against these two columns, but I hope I am wrong. I don't believe the JOINs across tables is an issue, or event_values needing to be stored in the TOAST storage due to the size to be an issue (I have tried with truncated test values, all of the same length, 128 chars and the results still take 60+ seconds).

From running *EXPLAIN ANALYSE* it appears no matter how I tweak the queries or tables, most of the time is spent searching the tables sequentially.

Am I simply spending time trying to make Postgres and full text search suit a problem it may never work (or at least have acceptable performance) for? Or should I look at other solutions e.g. One possible advantage of the data is it is 'immutable' and never updated once persisted, so something syncing the data to something like Elasticsearch and running search queries against it first might be a solution.

I would really like to use Postgres for this as I've seen it is possible, and read several articles where fantastic performance has been achieved - but maybe this data just isn't suited?

Edit;

Due to the size of the values (some of these could be large JSON blobs, several 100Kbs), the GIN index on **event_values** is based on the MD5 hash - for equality checks the index is used but never for searching as expected. For **event_keys** the GIN index is against the key_name column. Users can search against key names, values or both, for example "List all event keys beginning with 'meta.hashes'"

Comment: Normalizing the data was a good idea. Please also add the index definition, the queries and their execution plans to the question.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe since it's a work project it's difficult to add these without having to rename alot of things (and possibly break it ;)) - I believe the main issue is the type of data, the volume and the queries we want to run. After testing out with some static data (added several columns for common key names) and added the index and performance was 1000x better... unfortunately we won't know the key names in advance, and we still have the issue of the oversized data

Comment: If you cannot disclose the definitions and queries, you should hire a consultant who can sign a non-disclosure agreement. Usually money is no issue when secrecy is important.